# Flash error message appearing once after leaving the page the error came from (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The user sign up of my app displays success or error messages stored in flash. Problem is, if the user signup fails, the message appears. But if then, the user leaves that page, the flash message still appears in whichever page it is. If you refresh that page, it disappears.

This is the relevant code of the users controller:

```
 def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save 
      flash[:status] = {}
      flash[:status][:type], flash[:status][:message]  = 'success', 'Welcome to secondappr'   
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:status] = {}
      flash[:status][:type], flash[:status][:message] = "error", "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, 'error' )} caused your signup attempt to FAIL:" 
      flash[:details] = @user.errors.full_messages.each { |e| e }
      @user.password = ''
      @user.password_confirmation = ''
      @title = "Sign up#{ @puns.sample }"     
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This is the part of the application layout view that displays flash messages:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
 <div class='flash <%= flash[:status][:type]%>'>
    <%= content_tag(:strong, flash[:status][:message]) %>
    <ul class="details">
        <% if flash[:details]  %>
            <% flash[:details].each do |d| %>
                <%= content_tag(:li, d) %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `flash` is cleared between requests.

Your `create` method leads to a different number of requests depending on if the signup succeeds or not. If it does, the `redirect_to` creates a new request, which displays and then clears `flash`. This is the desired behavior.

When the signup fails, you are setting `flash` and then rendering a view, which doesn't create a new request like redirecting does. This means that your flash message is displayed in the current request and not cleared until **after** the following request. That's why it seems to be lasting one extra page view.

This exactly the situation for which `flash.now` was designed. From the docs:

> Sets a flash that will not be available to the next action, only to the current.
>
> `flash.now[:message] = "Hello current action"`
>
> This method enables you to use the flash as a central messaging system in your app. When you need to pass an object to the next action, you use the standard flash assign ([]=). When you need to pass an object to the current action, you use now, and your object will vanish when the current action is done.
>
> Entries set via now are accessed the same way as standard entries: `flash['my-key']`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally `flash` will apply to the next request. In your case, if the user can't be saved, you're rendering within the current request, not redirecting to a new one. So you need to use `flash.now` instead (inside your `else` block only):

```
else
  flash.now[:status] = {}
  flash.now[:status][:type], flash.now[:status][:message] = "error", "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, 'error' )} caused your signup attempt to FAIL:" 
  flash.now[:details] = @user.errors.full_messages.each { |e| e }
  @user.password = ''
  @user.password_confirmation = ''
  @title = "Sign up#{ @puns.sample }"     
  render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Although that is a bit...confusing, isn't it? I don`t really understand it